# Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Given a React code:

```
 <script type="text/babel">
              var Var = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                  return (
                    var args = {
                      "q": "data",
                      "offset": "0"
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                  ....headers and other stuff).done(function(JSONdata) {
                  console.log(JSONdata);

                }).fail(function() {
                  alert("You have an error");
                });
              );
            }
          });
          ReactDOM.render(<Var />, document.getElementById('div'));
```

Im getting error `Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token` that shows the lines:

```
            render: function() {
              return (
                var args = {
                  "q": "data",
                  "offset": "0"
                };
```

I think it has to do with the **curly brackets**, but what is the right way to write them inside React module? Or what is the actual error here ?

I have babel and react src already included in my html file. I need all of the key-values in `args` in order to send a request by ajax.

Comment: How you're returning makes no sense. JSX or elements are supposed to be in the return, or else use braces instead of parentheses and not in the `render` function, with `args : { ... }`

Comment: i think the `return (` is a line gone wrong. I cannot make any sense of it together with the following lines.

Comment: @ASDFGerte It's Babel

Comment: Can you show all the code?

Comment: can you show to code inside your return

Comment: Could you include the full source?

Comment: @epascarello updated

Comment: Why are you trying to render an object? No JS should b inside the return statement (excluding elements)

Comment: You're returning an object and nothing else. The object should be outside of this. Try returning something simple, see if this resolves your error.

Comment: @AndrewL., where should i put it then ?

Comment: @Michael Define the variable outside the return. Inside the render should still be OK. Inside your return, you need to return elements. Check out this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution for that is just wrap your return that just automatically execute it
into a function

```
return (function(){
    var args = {
      "q": "data",
      "offset": "0"
    };

    $.ajax({
  ....headers and other stuff).done(function(JSONdata) {
    console.log(JSONdata);

    }).fail(function() {
      alert("You have an error");
    });
});
```

so your code will be like this

```
var Var = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (function(){
            var args = {
              "q": "data",
              "offset": "0"
            };

            $.ajax({
          ....headers and other stuff).done(function(JSONdata) {
            console.log(JSONdata);

            }).fail(function() {
              alert("You have an error");
            });
        })();
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Var />, document.getElementById('div'));
```